# Predict future sales with LSTM and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am following this LSTM tutorial [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-sales-611cb5a252de) (with this [notebook](https://gist.github.com/karamanbk/fae78e4b0894cc0812812e4e600e5860)). The LSTM model predicts sales data. In the last image you can see the prediction and comparison to the live data. I build the model given in the example. But now I would like to make a prediction for the next year.

I tried already for hours to get a prediction for the year 2018 but without success. I have to say that I am pretty new to Python. Really appreciate if you could help me. Thanks a lot in advance!

Best,
Philipp

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. You start by predicting with your last avalaible data using your trained model.
2. With these predictions, you feed them to you network, get new predictions and reinject them in your network.
3. And you repeat the operation to predict for a year.

Comment: Do I need to change the 'y_pred' in line 36? I think I need to extend 'x_test' over the whole year? 
Sorry, I am a little bit confused, I am not sure what you mean with point 2 and 3. Thank you!